pyshadow and selenium says that button on site is inactive
pyshadow went threw all shadow roots on reddits post site to the selector #device-upload-button but it cant click on it. Error is Element with CSS #device-upload-button is not present on screen
i tried to refresh site or find if its clickable, it is. this is my code
post_url is https://www.reddit.com/r/NFT/submit/?type=IMAGE
driver.get(post_url)
            shadow = Shadow(driver)
            print(f"Opened post URL for subreddit: {subreddit}")
            element = shadow.find_element("#post-submit-form")
            element1 = shadow.find_element('#post-submit-form > section > faceplate-form-section:nth-child(6)')
            element2 = shadow.find_element("#post-composer_media")
            element3 = shadow.find_element('#fileInputInnerWrapper')
            element4 = shadow.find_elements('#fileInputInnerWrapper > div')
            element5 = shadow.find_element('#device-upload-button')
            element5.click()

i need to click on button, insert text from variable photo_path to the window which opens after button click and press enter to insert it
